# Mysql delete duplicate record based on one column and keep the longest length row

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guy I have following code to get the length of each row:

```
SELECT member_id, 
      (sum(length(first_name) + length(last_name) 
        + length(email) + length(mobile_phone))) as size
FROM my_table
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY size desc;
```

Since I have many records with same **email**, I want to delete duplicate and only keep the **longest length record**(means it have most information in that record). So how to do that?

sample data:

```
from:
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
    | id   | name   | Surnmae | email |address|
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
    | 1    |        | Lee     | aaa   |23 a st|
    | 2    | a      |         | aaa   |       |
    | 3    | c      |         | ccc   |       |
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+

to:
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
    | id   | name   | Surnmae | email |address|
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
    | 1    |        |  Lee    | aaa   |23 a st|
    | 3    | c      |         | ccc   |       |
    +------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

the id 1 have more information(longer length), that's why it got kept.

Comment: how to judge one record duplicated with another one? by name or member id? but I didn't see member id in your sample data.

Comment: what is your version of mySql? thanks

Comment: they should judged by email and I mention above as bold.

Answer (score 0):

My version of mySql is 5.6 and this query works. If not, let me know and will find answers for you. Thanks.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where member_id in (
SELECT member_id 
from (
 SELECT member_id,
       email,
      (sum(length(first_name) + length(last_name) 
        + length(email) + length(mobile_phone))) as size
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY member_id, email) m
join (SELECT email, max(size) as sz
from (
SELECT member_id,email,
      (sum(length(first_name) + length(last_name) 
        + length(email) + length(mobile_phone))) as size
FROM my_table
GROUP BY member_id,email
    ) t 
    GROUP BY email
 ) s on m.email=s.email and m.size =s.sz
 ) 

    Result:
member_id   first_name  last_name   email   mobile_phone
2                       Lee         aaa     168-168
3           c                       ccc     888-888
```

Comment: hey man, just tried the code with a small table, nothing changed after I ran the query. Then I tried will big data table which has around 80,000  records in, it stuck for a long time,

Comment: and should it be m.size>s.sz?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use variables:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.name is not null) + (t.surname is not null) + (t.address is not null) = 
          (select max( (t2.name is not null) + (t2.surname is not null) + (t2.address is not null) )
           from t t2
           where t2.email = t.email
          );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is what I made:select table1.*
from table1
where (t.firstname is not null) + (t.lastname is not null) + (t.address is not null) = 
          (select max( (t.firstname is not null) + (t.lastname is not null) + (t.address is not null) )
           from table1 t2
           where t2.email = t.email
          );
and the system says :#1054 - Unknown column 't.firstname' in 'where clause'